# Client does not read any data after reading another file

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I am writing a simple client/server application and I ran into a very weird issue.

I am trying to send a .zip file to the client and some more data after that.
Sending the .zip works fine, the server writes to the socket, the client reads from the socket, just as intended.

The problem is *right after that.*
The server runs fine and keeps writing to the socket, but the client just won't read anything. It gets stuck on the very next read() call, no matter what I try to send.

I've checked to see if the socket descriptors are alright, and they are. I also thought that maybe there is not enough data in the socket for the client to read, but there definitely is.

I also tried doing the same write/read before and after sending that .zip file: it works fine *before*, but client doesn't see it *after* sending that .zip.
I am out of ideas.

Here's the function I use to send the .zip:

```
typedef struct thData{
int idThread; //thread ID
int cl; //client descriptor
}thData;

void send_info(struct thData tdL)
{
    char file_path[256]="v1.zip";
    char sd_buffer[256];
    bzero(sd_buffer, 256); 

    FILE *fd = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    if(fd == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %s not found.\n", file_path);
        exit(1);
    }


    int read_size;
    int write_size;
    while((read_size = fread(sd_buffer, sizeof(char), 256, fd)) > 0)
    {
        if((write_size=write(tdL.cl, sd_buffer, read_size)) < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR: writing to client: \n");
            break;
        }
        bzero(sd_buffer, 256);
    }
}
```

And what I use to receive the .zip:

```
void receive_info(int sd) //sd being the socket descriptor
{
    char* file_path = "subject.zip";
    char received_buffer[256];

    int total_received=0;
    int total_wrote=0;

    FILE *fd = fopen(file_path, "wb");
    if(fd == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", file_path);
    else
    {
        bzero(received_buffer, 256); 
        int read_size = 0;
        while((read_size = read(sd, received_buffer, 256)) > 0) 
        {
            total_received=total_received+read_size;

            int write_size = fwrite(received_buffer, sizeof(char), read_size, fd);
            total_wrote=total_wrote+read_size;

            if(write_size < read_size)
            {
                perror("ERROR: \n");
            }
            bzero(received_buffer, 256);
            if (read_size == 0 || read_size != 256) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(read_size < 0)
        {

          perror("ERROR: reading: ");
          exit(1);

        }
        fclose(fd); 
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are reading too much.

In TCP there are no boundaries in the packets sent from one peer to the other. It is just a stream of bytes, and the pieces received from `recv/read()` bear no relation (in principle) to the pieces sent from `send/write()`.

Now, imagine that your ZIP file is 300 bytes long, and your extra data is 10 bytes long. Your sender code will do:

- write 256 bytes (first piece from ZIP).
- write 44 bytes (last piece from ZIP).
- write 10 bytes (the extra data).

And your receiver code will do:

- read 256, get 256 bytes (first piece from ZIP).
- read 256, get 54 bytes (last piece from ZIP plus the extra data).
- read XXX bytes, wait forever!

If you look carefully to the ZIP files you'll probably see those extra bytes at the end of `subject.zip`.

The solution, if you don't want to close and open another socket, is to make the protocol a bit more complicated. For example, you could send a structure before the file (a header) that includes the size of the file. That way the receiver will know when to stop reading.

PS: Note that your code has a few risky edges. For example, `write()` might not write all the given bytes, but you are not checking that; you are not closing the file...

PS2: I find curious that you feel the need to write `sizeof(char)` instead of just `1` but you write `256` instead of `sizeof(sd_buffer)`.